# selecting from one table if values in another table match a value in the first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, *City* and *driveRoute*. *City* has State and cityCode attributes. *driveRoute* has Origin and Destination attributes.

*City* data looks as follows: TX | ABI

*driveRoute* data looks as follows: ABI | ABQ

what I would like to have as a result would be: TX | 15 , where TX is Texas (example) and 15 is the number of routes within Texas (an example).

I am trying to get the distinct states with the count of routes in which a driveRoute has the same origin and destination state. What I have so far gets me the total number of routes with an origin or destination in a state:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state,COUNT(state) AS count
FROM driveRoute join
     City
     on origin = cityCode
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as text tables in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need two `join`s:

```
SELECT co.state, COUNT(*)
FROM driveRoute dr JOIn
     City co
     ON dr.origin = co.cityCode JOIN
     City cd
     ON dr.destination = cd.cityCode
WHERE co.state = cd.state
GROUP BY co.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the rows from `driveRoute` 
that contain `Origin` and `Destination` from the same `State` 
and then `GROUP BY State`:

```
SELECT t.State, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM (
  SELECT c2.State, driveRoute.*
  FROM  
    (driveRoute INNER JOIN City AS c1 ON driveRoute.Origin = c1.cityCode) 
    INNER JOIN City AS c2 ON driveRoute.Destination = c2.cityCode
  WHERE 
    c1.State = c2.state
) AS t
GROUP BY t.State
ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5;
```